# is it efficient to shrink an image using html img tags if the full size image is also being displayed?

Tags: html, image, thumbnails, scale

On a webpage I want to display both a fullsize version of an image as well as a thumbnail version of the same image. I understand that generally it saves on bandwidth to use a graphics program to shrink the image rather than using html img tags to shrink it.

But, if I'm already displaying the full size image on the page, presumably this will only be downloaded once in either situation so it would actually be more efficient to use the same full size image in both places on the page and scale it using html img tags to get the thumbnail version?

Thanks!

Comment: Will you *always* be displaying both thumbnail and full image at the same time? What's the purpose of that? Or will the full image initially be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's the same image source yes since you're only loading a single image and displaying it twice. If you made two separate images it would just add to the page load and use more bandwidth.